# Trying to understand R structure: what does a dot in function names signify?

Tags: r, function, structure

I am trying to learn how to use R. I can use it to do basic things like reading in data and running a t-test. However, I am struggling to understand the way R is structured (I am have a very mediocre java background).

What I don't understand is the way the functions are classified.

For example in `is.na(someVector)`, is `is` a class? Or for `read.csv`, is `csv` a method of the `read` class?

I need an easier way to learn the functions than simply memorizing them randomly. I like the idea of things belonging to other things. To me it seems like this gives a language a tree structure which makes learning more efficient.

Thank you

Sorry if this is an obvious question I am genuinely confused and have been reading/watching quite a few tutorials.

Comment: `is.na` and `read.csv` are the names of functions. You can access their respective help file by typing `?is.na` and `?read.csv`.

Comment: Would it then be correct to say that is.na() and is.numeric() are unrelated? Or do they belong to something?

Comment: `is` gets repeated for a number of functions all doing similar things, namely testing if the object has a particular characteristic: `is.vector` `is.numeric` `is.matrix` `is.function` etc etc. Same goes for `read.` , normally for importing data: `read.csv` `read.fwf` `read.fortran` etc. They are a naming convention.

Comment: You may also have a look at [**this presentation**](http://sumsar.net/files/academia/UseR_2013_R_naming_conventions_final.pdf) from the useR conference in 2013, on (the lack of) naming conventions of R functions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your confusion is entirely understandable, since R mixes two conventions of using (1) `.` as a general-purpose word separator (as in `is.na()`, `which.min()`, `update.formula()`, `data.frame()` ...) and (2) `.` as an indicator of an S3 method, `method.class` (i.e. `foo.bar()` would be the "foo" method for objects with class attribute "bar").  This makes functions like `summary.data.frame()` (i.e., the `summary` method for objects with class `data.frame`) especially confusing.

As @thelatemail points out above, there are some other sets of functions that repeat the same prefix for a variety of different options (as in `read.table()`, `read.delim()`, `read.fwf()` ...), but these are entirely conventional, not specified anywhere in the formal language definition.

```
dotfuns <- apropos("[a-z]\\.[a-z]")
dotstart <- gsub("\\.[a-zA-Z]+","",dotfuns)
head(dotstart)
tt <- table(dotstart)
head(rev(sort(tt)),10)
##  as   is  print  Sys  file summary dev format all sys 
## 118   51     32   18    17      16  16     15  14  13
```

(Some of these are actually S3 generics, some are not. For example, `Sys.*()`, `dev.*()`, and `file.*()` are not.)

Historically `_` was used as a shortcut for the assignment operator `<-` (before `=` was available as a synonym), so it wasn't available as a word separator.  I don't know offhand why camelCase wasn't adopted instead.

Confusingly, `methods("is")` returns `is.na()` among many others, but it is effectively just searching for functions whose names start with "is."; it warns that `"function 'is' appears not to be generic"`

[Rasmus Bååth's presentation on naming conventions](http://sumsar.net/files/academia/UseR_2013_R_naming_conventions_final.pdf) is informative and entertaining (if a little bit depressing).

**extra credit**: are there any dot-separated S3 method names, i.e. cases where a function name of the form `x.y.z` represents the `x.y` method for objects with class attribute `z` ?

**answer** (from Hadley Wickham in comments): `as.data.frame.data.frame()` wins.  `as.data.frame` is an S3 generic (*unlike*, say, `as.numeric`), and `as.data.frame.data.frame` is its method for `data.frame` objects. Its purpose (from `?as.data.frame`):

> If a data frame is supplied, all classes preceding ‘"data.frame"’
>        are stripped, and the row names are changed if that argument is
>        supplied.

Comment: I always found the `as.data.frame.matrix` function to be an egregious use of dots.

Comment: not technically, I think, because (1) `as` is **not** actually an S3 generic (compare `print` and `as` ...) and (2) `as` is not the dotted part.  (One of the limitations of the S3 methods is that they can't do multiple dispatch ...) But yes in the spirit of the thing.

Comment: The `print.summary.*` functions? But they are called by `summary` and you never have to type `print.summary.*`.

Comment: the `print.summary.*` methods are actually the `print` methods for objects of class `summary.*`, which are produced by `summary` methods.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that nothing beats `as.data.frame.data.frame()` - `as.data.frame()` is an S3 generic

Comment: Hmm, thank you for your detailed response. That is the kind of answer I was looking for. 
Is there a website/book/pdf with a good summary of R functions and and S3 methods and classes that one of you would recommend me?

 I wish it weren't organized like that I am a taxonomy junky (mostly aquatic insects) so I use trees to remember things. 

Thank you for all your help,
Nico